# Restkit overwriting local entity changes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, restkit

Hello tried using restkit with coredata. I think that it is great but I think that there is too much magic going on.

I have an issue, a user downloads a file and I set the entity downloaded property to YES. I restart the app and the app connects to the server which and reskit nulls my changes because the server doesn't have this parameter. Is there any way to prevent restkit from overriding my local entities?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to update existing objects? Do they have unique identities? Have you asked RestKit to match on those identities?

Comment: Yeah using unique identifiers. Issue happens if you try to i.e make a change to the entity locally, it gets overwritten the next time you connect using restkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `RKManagedObjectStore` instance, you need to supply it with a `managedObjectCache` - this is what gives it the ability to find existing items and prevent duplicates. You would often use an instance of `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache` for this.